# solve $\int_0^1\cos x^{1/3} dx$

Tags: integration

solve $$\int_0^1\cos x^{1/3} dx$$

My approach would be to use substitution and set $\cos x =t, dx = - \sin (t) dt$ which gives me $-\int_0^1t^{1/3} \sin( t) dt$ however then I'm stuck again...

Comment: Better start with $x=u^3$.

Comment: Just making sure, the power is on $x$, not cos correct?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla smart, and then $dx = 3u^2du$ correct?

Comment: @user88595 correct

Comment: @iveqy, correct. Now integrate by parts.

Answer (score 1):

For $n>-\dfrac12$ we have $\displaystyle\int_0^\frac\pi2\cos^{2n}x=\int_0^\frac\pi2\sin^{2n}x=\frac12\cdot B\Big(n+\tfrac12~;~\tfrac12\Big)$ . See [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals) for more details on their relationship to the [Beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and [$\Gamma$ functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). If however you are positive that the upper limit is indeed $1$ instead of $\dfrac\pi2$, then the result can only be expressed in terms of an [incomplete beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function), $\displaystyle\int_0^a\cos^{2n}x=\frac12\bigg[B\Big(n+\tfrac12~;~\tfrac12\Big)-B\Big(\cos^2a~;~n+\tfrac12~;~\tfrac12\Big)\bigg]$. In this particular case, $n=\dfrac16$ and $a=1$.